# Styling the admin bar in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, css, design

I know most of you would not style the admin bar, but I am going for a consistent look and feel and the issue is, I cannot find the classes responsible for creating:

[image]

The green tabbed section. I want the border and the green gone, hell I would love to edit this html piece but I can do what I need with HTML. I have tried inspecting it but cannot find the appropriate classes or Id's responsible for creating it.

help?

Comment: Why oh why do people fuss with styling. It just leads to anger, hate, suffering...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Green Calendar Tab]

I inspected the green box with the F12 developer tools and found it:

[image: F12 Developer Tools Markup]

The outer box has `id="Ribbon.Calendar"`. You can search for that in the markup to further inspect the inner elements.

## Edit

Why can't you target them? I just did.

I tested with: `#Ribbon\.Calendar { font-size:12px; }`

Is it because you aren't escaping the `.`?

[Special characters in CSS selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132793/special-characters-in-css-selectors)

Comment: While the ID is correct you cannot target it. any other ideas? the various classes assigned to it do not have anything to do with the over all look of the calendar tools tabs

Comment: yeah you can...

Comment: I didnt know you have to escape the `.`

Comment: yeah, otherwise it reads `#Ribbon.Calendar` as "the element with `id="Ribbon"` and `class="Calendar"`" ;)

Comment: So I tried your idea and for me, at least, the style doesnt stick. It shows up in chrome, for example I tried `#Ribbon\.Calendar { background-color:white !important; }` it shows up in the chrome inspector - but does not apply the styles.

Comment: Try `#Ribbon\.Calendar .ms-cui-cg-t { background:White; }`... and read up on specificity http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/ If you have further questions about CSS, make a new post.